# Seemingly Random Perl Errors

Tags: perl

My Perl program contains two blocks similar to this one:

```
open my $file, '>', $filename or do{
    print "Failed to open file\nFile not saved\n";
    return;
}
```

When I run it I get this:

```
"my" variable @lines masks earlier declaration in same scope at myfile.pl line 43.
"my" variable @args masks earlier declaration in same scope at myfile.pl line 43.
"my" variable @args masks earlier declaration in same statement at myfile.pl line 43.
"my" variable @args masks earlier declaration in same scope at myfile.pl line 47.
syntax error at myfile.pl line 19, near "$i ("
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at myfile.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at myfile.pl line 21.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at myfile.pl line 21.
Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at myfile.pl line 23.
syntax error at myfile.pl line 24, near "}"
syntax error at myfile.pl line 35, near "}"
syntax error at myfile.pl line 44, near "}"
syntax error at myfile.pl line 54, near "}"
Can't use global @_ in "my" at myfile.pl line 57, near ", $_"
myfile.pl has too many errors.
```

But when I replace it with this:

```
do{
    print "Failed to open file\nFile not saved\n";
    return;
}unless open my $file, '>', $filename;
```

All the errors instantly disappear and the program runs fine. I have `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Does anyone understand why this is happening? Is there something wrong with my parentheses or something? Changing the spacing in the `open` function does nothing.

**EDIT**: I have replaced the `print` statements with `warn`.

Comment: Use `warn` instead of `print`, or, at least `print STDERR` ... Also, just croak and let the calling code catch the exception.

Comment: You do not actually need a block to execute multiple statements. You can just use a comma separated list `or print "...", return;` A bit more correct is to use parentheses on the print so it does not include the following code: `or print("..."), return;` Though you should probably use `warn` or `croak` instead, like @SinanÜnür says.

Comment: @TLP: But that doesn't help with the problem—the scoping of the file handle?

Comment: @Borodin Removing the scoping problem does not help with the scoping problem...?

Comment: @TLP: Please explain. You didn't mention scoping, and removing the block and using a comma instead of a semicolon changes nothing about the scoping.

Comment: The error is outside of the code you posted. For a proper fix, please actually provide the relevant code!

Comment: When you get a batch of errors like that, it _usually_ means you've done something like miss a semicolon or close bracket. But without the code and actual errors, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Sobrique There should be a semi-colon after the `do` block. Nice catch. It is a common mistake, which is perhaps the answer.

Comment: @TLP @Sobrique Thanks, I didn't know about the semi-colon after `do` blocks. I was reading a Perl tutorial about flow control and when I saw the errors I was convinced it was something in the `open` part and didn't notice the `;`. Problem solved.

Comment: @Arc676: I'm unclear how a missing semicolon can cause a `masks earlier declaration` warning. It is most likely to result in a syntax error. Please would you explain further.

Comment: @Borodin Frankly, I have no idea either. I'm new to Perl. All I can tell you is that when I add the semi colon the program runs. When I remove it, I get 4 `masks earlier declaration` errors, 5 syntax errors, 4 `Global variable requires package name` errors, and `Can't use global @_ in "my"`. I will add the exact errors to the question.

Comment: Ah so you *do* get syntax errors. That's comforting at least. I wrote my solution assuming that you were getting *only* `masks earlier declaration` warnings. I don't suppose you could share your complete source, perhaps on pastebin?

Comment: I can't get PasteBin to work where I am. Should I paste the complete code into the question?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case

```
open ( my $file, '>', $filename ) or do {
  print "Failed to open file\nFile not saved\n";
  return;
}
```

the `my $file` is in scope outside the `do` block, whereas in

```
do {
  print "Failed to open file\nFile not saved\n";
  return;
} unless open my $file, '>', $filename;
```

it is local to the block. Note that that also means you can't use `$file` to write to after you have opened it as it is immediately closed again.

You can

- Use different identifiers for each file handle
- Omit the `my` from all `open` calls after the first
- Enclose each `open`, and the subsequent file operations, inside its own block, like this

  ```
  {
    open( my $file, '>', $filename ) or do{
      print "Failed to open file\nFile not saved\n";
      return;
    };

    # Write to $file
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I take it this has something to do with a subroutine. Otherwise, why do you have a `return`?

Use a standard `if` statement. This way, it's just clearer what the program is doing:

```
my $file;
if ( not open $file, ">", $filename ) {
    warn qq(Failed to open file "$filename"\nFile not saved\n);
    return;
}
```

Notice:

- I have to define `$file` outside of my `if`. Otherwise, `$file` becomes undefined outside of my `if`. Probably not what you want. (And is what is causing your problems).
- I also use `warn`. This prints to `STDERR` rather than `STDOUT`. It also alerts a developer skimming through your code that this is some sort of error message and might be important to note.

The latest style programming style is to lets subroutines die on errors. This means you can simply do this in your subroutine:

```
open my $fh, ">", $filename
     or die qq(Can't open "$filename"\n);
```

Now, if the developer doesn't want the program to die, the developer now has to actively handle the error with an `eval`:

```
my $fh;
eval {
     $fh = openlog ( $filename );
};
if ( $@ ) {
     warn qq(Can't open log file "$filename". No log will be written);
}
```

This is the way *exception handling* programming languages like Python and Java force developers to face up to errors.  Otherwise, a developer could simply assume that the subroutine worked. In Perl, you see stuff like this all the time:

```
send_email( email_address( $user ), $message );
```

Um... Did `email_address()` actually return an email address before the program attempts to send out an email?